# Can someone provide resources on human electromagnetic frequencies?

Tags: human-biology

Pardon all of my questions below.  I'm basically looking to find online resources regarding my inquiry.  If you can answer any of them off the bat, that would be awesome!!

It seems that humans and mammals give off certain frequencies from our nervous systems.  For example, dogs are able to sense when their master is coming home, even when their distance is close to a mile away.  Also, cats are able to sense when a human is about to die.  They can feel the frequency the person is giving off, and react differently.

1. Where can I learn more about this frequency that humans give off?
2. Has anyone ever done research on this subject?
3. Is this electromagnetic frequency or something else?
4. Are there devices that can measure this frequency that the human nervous system gives off?
5. Are there devices that can generate this frequency that the human nervous system gives off?

Comment: are there any references at all about the frequencies?  or is it a case of other senses at play?

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15197761

Comment: " For example, dogs are able to sense when their master is coming home, even when their distance is close to a mile away."  Do you have a citation for that?

Comment: I saw it on a documentary, but I cannot recall which one it was.  It might not have been one mile, but it was a long distance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but much of this is pseudoscience. While animals do release electromagnetic radiation, mammals are not capable of detecting it. For example, cats may be able to sense that someone is about to die because they have an _excellent_ sense of smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, you could learn about Bioelectromagnetics which is the study of the interaction between electromagnetic fields and biological entities ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioelectromagnetics)). Electro-magnetic fields are generated by the heart, brain, tissues and cells. These fields are in-turn affected by temperature and the overall mood of a person ([reference](http://www.heartmath.org/templates/ihm/articles/infographic/2013/mysteries-of-the-heart/index.php)).

There is a lot of research that is being conducted in the field. You can find a lot of papers relating to the field with a [simple search](http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?start=0&q=human%20electromagnetic%20fields&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&as_vis=1) on Google Scholar.

Well technically electromagnetic fields.

There are instruments to measure EMF which are detailed in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMF_measurement). Here is an article on an instrument made to measure the electromagnetic field of the heart ([reference](http://phys.org/news179751368.html)).

Generally, if you have measured the electromagnetic fields in different parts of the body (eg: [this article](http://www.academia.edu/2968057/_The_Exposure_of_Humans_to_the_Electromagnetic_Fields_) states that the electric field of the heart is up to 50 mV/m, and that of the brain and other vital organs up to 5 mV/m) then it shouldn't be too hard to generate them seeing that EMF generated is a low value ([reference](http://www.ehow.com/how_5135610_create-electromagnetic-field.html)).